# Combine two functions? Javascript and AJAX api call with throbber

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preloader, throbber

I have a function getShare which creates a script and then calls an url shortener api which then returns a shortened url and sets that link to an input box's value.

Secondly I also have this function which I'm trying get to work with the first. So far I've only been able to .show the loader gif but not hide it when the function is successful.

EDIT: Below is updated code with my original script inside the response.success but i'm get a message in the console saying Failed to load resource and a 404 - the missing url is shown to be `http://b1t.co/Site/api/External/MakeUrlWithGet?callback=apiCallback&_=1391704846002`

```
function getShare(url)
{ 
    $('#loader').show(); // show loading...
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback:'apiCallback', // this will be send to api as ?callback=apiCallback because this api do not want to work with default $ callback function name
        url: 'http://b1t.co/Site/api/External/MakeUrlWithGet',
        data: {'url':url},
        success: function(response){
            $('#loader').hide(); // hide loading...
            //respponse = {success: true, url: "http://sdfsdfs", shortUrl: "http://b1t.co/qz"} 
            if(response.success){

                {       
                var s = document.createElement('script');
                var browserUrl = document.location.href;
                //alert(browserUrl);
                if (browserUrl.indexOf("?") != -1){
                        browserUrl = browserUrl.split("?");
                        browserUrl = browserUrl[0];
                }
                //alert(browserUrl);

                var gifUrl = $('#gif_input').value;
                var vidUrl = $('#gif_input').value;
                //alert(gifUrl + "|" + vidUrl);

                url = encodeURIComponent(browserUrl + "?gifVid=" + gifUrl + "|" + vidUrl);
                //alert(encodeURIComponent("&"));
                s.id = 'dynScript';
                s.type='text/javascript';
                s.src = "http://b1t.co/Site/api/External/MakeUrlWithGet?callback=resultsCallBack&url=" + url;
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
                }

function resultsCallBack(data)
{
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
    $("#input-url").val(obj.shortUrl);
    }
    }
},
    error:function(){
    $('#loader').hide();
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at once. James_1x0 already answered your question. You should post a new question for your 404 problem. I get a 404 when typing that URL, I don't know why you'd expect the AJAX call not to get a 404

Comment: @JuanMendes Because I'm new to this, that's why. I do appreciate you pointing out proper etiquette for asking questions though, even with your passive aggressive tone.

Comment: "Please don't ask two questions at once". I thought that was a nice way to put it. I'm just showing you the ropes around here. That keeps the questions useful to other people besides just you. You probably noticed you aren't getting much help, because your question is twofold, and the issues aren't related. Asking a new question will get you an answer much more quickly

Comment: I wasn't trying to piss you off, and I did try to guide you (and you took offense to it). The URL `http://b1t.co/Site/api/External/MakeUrlWithGet` gives you a 404 whenI type it into the URL box. I still don't know how you'd expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

#### There's no need to "combine" it.

What someone is suggesting is a regular ajax method. Just move your js scripts you want executed on success, inside the `success:` callback.

Read more about the ajax method at another answer I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285630/writing-my-first-rest-api-call-to-a-webservice-endpoint-post/21286810#21286810 or jQuery's docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

*Note: to use this you will need jQuery and probably an XDR plugin for the ajax to support < IE 10*

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I updated my answer too. Could you give it a look? I'm not sure why I'm getting an error for it. Thank you!

Comment: @dMaller You should ask a new question, but are you testing locally...? If you're testing right off your machine, you won't be able to complete an ajax call - only hosted on a server will you be able to make the call. Also for quick reference, check the google chrome dev tools "Network" section to see the response you get back from the API or whatever resource you're making that ajax call to.